# Checking the status of child process

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork

Hi am bit new to c programming.I have the following piece of code, basically the program need to check the status of the child process and parent waits until the child terminates and then prints "the child has terminated". But I tried the WNOHANG, but the somehow my second checking is not working/or i can't stop the child process. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;
    int ppid;
    int status;
    pid=vfork();
    pid_t return_pid = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);

    if (pid<0) {
        printf("\n Error ");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid==0) {
        printf("\n Hello I am the child process ");
        printf("\n My pid is %d %d ",return_pid, getpid());
        exit(0);
    } else if (return_pid == pid) {
            printf("child is finished %d %d", return_pid, pid);
            exit(0);
    } else {
        printf("\n Hello I am the parent process %d %d", return_pid, pid);
        printf("\n My actual pid is %d %d \n ",return_pid, getpid());
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, from `vfork()` manual page: "_The child must not return from the current function or call exit(3), but may  call _exit(2)._" You are not allowed to `exit` on the third line of the child.

Comment: And there are other limitations on `vfork()` too — calling `waitpid()` isn't valid.  In my book, `vfork()` is too restrictive to be of use; I never use it.

Comment: I think you should be using fork here instead of vfork. With vfork, the parent is suspended until the child completes, so your parent really has nothing to check and there is no parallelism here. With fork, both parent and child can run in parallel, and so the check by the parent is interesting and useful. That sounds like the point of the assignment: to experiment with parallelism.

Comment: when i tried remove the vfork the parent always run first. I want the parent to wait until the child terminates and then prints "the child has terminated".

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if maybe your waitpid is in the wrong location. Checking `man 2 wait` and reading what the argument of pid stands for

> The pid parameter specifies the set of child processes for which to wait.  If pid is -1, the call waits for any child process.  **If pid is 0, the call waits for any child
>        process in the process group of the caller.**  If pid is greater than zero, the call waits for the process with process id pid.  If pid is less than -1, the call waits for any
>        process whose process group id equals the absolute value of pid.

The bold text, to me, indicates that the child could be waiting on itself? The value of vfork will return 0 for the child.

Also, the WNOHANG option will cause waitpid to return immediately if the child has not exited, meaning the parent will not wait for the child to finish. If the child process has finished then it will return the pid of the child.